# I want to display fields of opportunity object on case record page by using LWC but not able displaly because i am very new to LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Created a lwc but not displaying

**HTML file**

```html
<template>
   <lightning-card  title="Opportunity Details" icon-name="custom:custom63">
                <!--<template if:true={contacts.data}>
                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="contact">
                    <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.Name}</p>-->
                    <div class="slds-m-around_medium" style="width:200px"></div>
       <!-- <div class="slds-p-bottom_large slds-p-left_large" style="width:200px">-->
    
           
        >
            <div class="slds-box" >
              <!--  <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
                </lightning-output-field>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Birthdate">
                </lightning-output-field>-->

                <!--Opportunity fields-->
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
                </lightning-output-field>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="FINRA_CRD__c">
                </lightning-output-field>
                <lightning-output-field field-name="Business_Name__c">
                </lightning-output-field>
          </div>
    </lightning-card>
         
</template>
```

**JS file**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunity from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityDetails.getOpportunity';

export default class OpportunityRec extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;
    @wire(getOpportunity, {recordId: '$recordId'}) contacts; 
}
```

**Apex class**

```java
public class OpportunityDetails{
    
    @AuraEnabled( cacheable = true )
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunity(Id recordId) {
      System.debug('@@'+recordId);  
        Case caseRec= [Select id,contactId from case where Id =:recordId];
        System.debug('@@'+caseRec);
        if(caseRec!=null){
                return [SELECT Id, Account_Data_Received__c, Additional_Brokerage__c 
            FROM Opportunity where Contact__c  =:caseRec.contactId];    
        }else{
            return null;
        }
            
    }
        

}
```

I tried but not displaying anything.
Please I need the proper code and component

Comment: Please can anyone help on this

Answer (score 0):

Your Apex code is incorrect; it will throw an exception if the record is not found. Use a list if you want to avoid this problem.

```
// Exception can be thrown here. Do not do this.
Case caseRec= [Select id,contactId from case where Id =:recordId];

// This is safe:
Case[] cases = [SELECT ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id = :recordId];
if(cases.isEmpty()) {
  return new List<Opportunity>();
}
return [SELECT Account_Data_Received__c, Additional_Brokerage__c
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Contact__c = :cases[0].ContactId];
}
```

So, your code can look more like this:

```
public class OpportunityDetails {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Opportunity> getOpportunity(Id recordId) {
        Case[] cases = [SELECT ContactId FROM Case WHERE Id = :recordId];
        if(cases.isEmpty()) {
            return new List<Opportunity>();
        }
        return [SELECT Id, Account_Data_Received__c, Additional_Brokerage__c 
            FROM Opportunity WHERE Contact__c  =:cases[0].ContactId];    
    }
}
```

---

`lightning-output-field` requires the use of `lightning-record-form`,  `lightning-record-edit-form`, or `lightning-record-view-form`. Either use one of these components (which will require changes to your Apex as well), or use `lightning-input` or another component as you need (e.g. `lightning-formatted-text`).

Comment: But not able display by using above code

Comment: I can see the component on record page but it is not displaying the fields on UI

Comment: hi please can anyone help on this

Comment: @Ranadheer Saying things like "cannot see" or it "does not work" is not helpful to diagnosing the problem. What does your code look like now, after making the changes? Do you see any errors on the "Developer Console" (F12)? Any popup messages? Anything you can provide that would be helpful would help us help you.

Comment: no errors in devconsole but component is visible but fields are not displaying